# Name of this freshwater fish with diamond shaped spots and a single top fin, caught in a river in South Florida, USA

Tags: fish, fish-identification

I don't know many fish so I am trying to get names of fish as I catch them. Can you tell from these pictures what type of fish this is? Unfortunately, I gut hooked this one. It was caught in a river in South Florida.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks a lot like a spotted sunfish but I'm not confident.

Comment: @whatsisname Thank you for your reply. That does look very close to this. Two things stand out to me that are different though. This fish does not have the black spot over the gill area and also it is more narrow and long instead of short and tall. Those differences may be due to gender and variation based on age and location I guess but I feel like this may be different. Another thing is that this fish has 4 - 6 teeth, you can see one in the last picture. Do sunfish have teeth?

Comment: Could it be a type of snapper? Looks kinda of like http://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/profiles/saltwater/snapper/cubera-snapper/  This river is not strictly freshwater, its kind of brackish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a [mangrove snapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangrove_snapper), (there are quite a few different names of snapper) and I am making the identification on two things, the pattern of diamond shaped spots and the top fin being whole and not split into two fins..

See this picture of a mangrove snapper.

[image]

[Image Source](http://www.texasbbqforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=10580)

Comment: Thank you, yes that does look just like it!